# Unidentified port evading firewall

Tags: security, firewall, ufw

I am trying to tighten up security on my Ubuntu 16.04 Server. I noticed a port 115 open when i run `ufw status` on SSH.

[image]

I want to close this sneaky port, so I run `ufw delete allow 115`.

[image]

This is very strange.

why a port is open and the firewall has no idea about it? How can I block the port using `ufw`?

Comment: Do you have SFTP running on the server? That uses port 115.

Answer (score 1):

`ufw delete` is used to delete any existing firewall rule.

To block a port you can use:

```
sudo ufw deny <port>/<optional: protocol>
```

To allow a port, use

```
sudo ufw allow <port>/<optional: protocol>
```

**Example:**

To deny tcp and udp packets on port 53

```
sudo ufw deny 53
```

To deny incoming tcp packets on port 53

```
sudo ufw deny 53/tcp
```

To deny incoming udp packets on port 53

```
sudo ufw deny 53/udp
```

For more see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW